# How to configure m2m relationship in Sonata Admin?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I am using Symfony 2.6.1.

Entities configuration: http://pastebin.com/rMkYHjkE

Admin class:

```
class PlaceAdmin extends Admin
{
    // Fields to be shown on create/edit forms
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            //other fields
            ->add('types', 'collection', array(
                'type'         => new PlaceType,
                'allow_add'    => true,
            ));
        ;
    }
    //other stuff
}
```

When I am trying to edit selected entity:

> Expected argument of type "string,
>   Symfony\Component\Form\ResolvedFormTypeInterface or
>   Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface",
>   "Syloc\Bundle\GooglePlacesBundle\Entity\PlaceType" given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#type):

> This is the field type for each item in this collection (e.g. text, choice, etc). For example, if you have an array of email addresses, you'd use the email type. If you want to embed a collection of some other form, create a new instance of your form type and pass it as this option.

So you would want to do something like:

```
class PlaceAdmin extends Admin
{
    // Fields to be shown on create/edit forms
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            //other fields
            ->add('types', 'collection', array(
                'type'         => 'text',
                'allow_add'    => true,
            ));
        ;
    }
    //other stuff
}
```

You don't define an Entity Type for a `collection` Form Type. Perhaps you were also looking to do [`sonata_type_collection`](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-collection), and not just `collection`? You also shouldn't need to pass the child Entity type through this Form Type as it's automatically resolved from the Entity property.